# Weight Paint not going away where needed

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I am modeling a zebra but am running into the issue of the ear has some of the mane selected with the weight paint. I try to use the F Subtract brush but it is not producing the desired results as the main weight paint is not changing and it is also unselecting part of the ear. Any ideas?

Before Stroke
[image]
After Stroke[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to paint weights if you mask your selection. In *Edit Mode* select the vertices you wish to work on, and then in *Weight Paint Mode* press <kbd>M</kbd>...

[image]

Back in *Edit Mode* you can also check the Vertex groups and manually remove unwanted vertices...

[image]